# Why do i have to put str.length()-3? Please help explain

Tags: java, string

I am new to programming and i don't quite get why i have to put str.length()-3.If someone can explain it to me that would be great.
        return cats == dogs; 
(using coding bats code)

```
public static boolean catDog(String str) {
    int cats = 0;
    int dogs = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-3; i++) {
        if (str.substring(i, i+3).equals("cat"))
            cats += 1;
        if (str.substring(i, i+3).equals("dog"))
            dogs += 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here a example:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 3; i++) { //starts the interation at i = 0

    if (str.substring(0, 0 + 3).equals("cat")) cats += 1; //substring from your first character(character at Index[0] till your 3th character)
    if (str.substring(0, 0 + 3).equals("dog")) dogs += 1; //substring from your first character(character at Index[0] till your 3th character)
}
```

if you have a String `"helloWorld"` your programm would check the first 3 characters of the String `"hel"oworld`, if they are either "cat" or "dog"

after that your `for-loop` iterates the next number:

```
if (str.substring(1, 1 + 3).equals("cat")) cats += 1; //substring from your second character(character at Index[1] till your 4th character)
        if (str.substring(1, 1 + 3).equals("dog")) dogs += 1; //substring from your second character(character at Index[1] till your 4th character)
    }
```

in our `helloWorld` example your program would check if `h"ell"oWorld` would be either "cat" or  "dog"...After that, the iteration increments once again and so on...

Comment: then please approve of my answere :D

Comment: Why have you removed your approval of my answere?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading on for loops: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

This iterator uses the second value as the delimiter for the loop. It tells the loop how long it should continue looping for. So in your case you are saying until the total length of the string minus 3.

so if you had a length of 10 for `str.length()`, then you would stop at `7` because `str.length()-3 == 7`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your advice isn't bad, but it turns out that the OP is working with Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: but why do i have to put -3 there? Cant i just leave it as it is?

Comment: @MaxH. you don't *have to* do that, but since you'll never find a three-character string in the last one or two characters of the search string, it just saves a little work.

Comment: i consider loops a concept more than a language specific implementation, heres an article for JAVA, however. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for 3-character strings inside a bigger string. How likely is it that you'll find the string "cat" starting at the second-to-last character of the search string?  That's what the `- 3` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if I extract a well named variable for you:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 3; i++) {
        String threeCharactersStartingAti = str.substring(i, i + 3);
        if (threeCharactersStartingAti.equals("cat")) cats += 1;
        if (threeCharactersStartingAti.equals("dog")) dogs += 1;
    }
```

Then explain that the code is looking at the 3 characters that start at position `i`. So for a string that is 5 long `"ABCDE"`, the values in the loop will be:

```
i=0 => threeCharactersStartingAti = "ABC"
i=1 => threeCharactersStartingAti = "BCD"
i=2 => threeCharactersStartingAti = "CDE"
```

That's it, I don't want to carry on because for `i>=str.length()-3` there isn't enough characters left in the string to get 3.

Comment: You're welcome, but no need to thank people, just click the grey up arrow if you like a post.